# Bouncing Ball Game, Mouse Detect Event, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, coordinates, dom-events

I've already created a bouncing ball which bounces off the walls of the HTML5 Canvas that I have specified.

My goal is to make a "Game Over" screen appear when the pointer (mouse) hovers over the ball.

I have already searched and found some tutorials on mouse events in Javascript, but I'm not really sure how to implement them into my code =/.

Any help would be amazing.

```
<script>
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) + 1);
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);

var dx = 2;
var dy = 4;

function begin()
{
    gameCanvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    context = gameCanvas.getContext('2d');
    return setInterval (draw, 20);
}

begin();


function draw()
{
    context.clearRect(0,0,600,300);
    context.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x,y,80,0,Math.PI*2,true); 
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();

    if (x < 0 || x > 600) dx=-dx

    if (y < 0 || y > 300) dy=-dy;

    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

gameCanvas.onmousemove = function (e)
{
    var gameCanvas = e.target;
    var context = gameCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var coords = RGraph.getMouseXY(e);
}
```

Comment: offtopic: setInterval (draw, 20) is not a good idea. This post explain new techiniques http://nokarma.org/2011/02/02/javascript-game-development-the-game-loop/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the mouse is hovering over the ball (hit test) by checking the distance of the ball to the cursor. If the distance is smaller than radius of the ball, it means that the mouse is over the ball.

Note, that you need to adjust the code below to your needs
Example:

```
var mouse_x = 10, mouse_y = 10, ball_x = 10, ball_y = 10, ball_radius = 70, is_game_over = false

if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow( mouse_x - ball_x, 2 ) + Math.pow( mouse_x - ball_x, 2 )) < ball_radius && !is_game_over ) {
    console.log('Cursor is over the mouse, game over')
    is_game_over = true
}
```

Do it for every frame update.

Answer (score 1):

you can add onmousemove=SetValues() to your body element like so:

```
<body onmousemove=SetValues()>
```

and change your code to this:

```
<script>
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) + 1);
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);

var dx = 2;
var dy = 4;

var mouseX;
var mouseY;

function setValues(e)
{
    mouseX = e.pageX; //get mouse x
    mouseY = e.pageY; //get mouse y
}

function begin()
{
    gameCanvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    context = gameCanvas.getContext('2d');
    return setInterval (draw, 20);
}

begin();


function draw()
{
    context.clearRect(0,0,600,300);
    context.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x,y,80,0,Math.PI*2,true); 
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();

    if (x < 0 || x > 600) dx=-dx

    if (y < 0 || y > 300) dy=-dy;

    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    //check if the mouse is on the ball
    var centerX = x + 80; //center of ball
    var centerY = y; //center of ball

    if(Math.pow((mouseX - centerX), 2) + Math.pow((mouseY - centerY), 2) <= 6400){
        //do whatever to end game
    }
}
```